# onResume() get called when press back button

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, back-stack

There is a strange thing happening when I press back button, the same `Activity`'s `onResume()` method is getting called.

Does it mean there are more than one instances of this `Activity` in stack?

Can someone here tell me what is happening?

Edit:

```
12-27 19:51:44.595: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x1947378
12-27 19:51:44.624: I/not null recipientlist(10777): show
12-27 19:51:44.624: I/in getconversation for complete mesages(10777): show
12-27 19:51:44.812: D/dalvikvm(10777): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1064K, 17% free 10334K/12359K, paused 2ms+3ms
12-27 19:51:45.606: D/JpgDecHal(10777): JpgDecHal::JpgDecHal
12-27 19:51:45.607: D/skia(10777): The file input width: 102, height: 102, output width: 102, height: 102, format: 6, prefer size: 0, dither: 0
12-27 19:51:45.607: D/JpgDecHal(10777): JpgDecHal::start -> config jpeg path
12-27 19:51:45.607: D/JpgDecHal(10777): Decoder Src Addr:0x19a9100, width/height:[102, 102]           
12-27 19:51:45.607: D/JpgDecHal(10777): Decoder Dst Addr:0x415e7450, width/height:[102, 102], format:3
12-27 19:51:45.607: D/JpgDecHal(10777): Decoder Dither:0, RangeDecode:0 [6649455 0 0 0]
12-27 19:51:45.610: D/JpgDecHal(10777): jpeg decoder result:0 
12-27 19:51:45.613: D/JpgDecHal(10777): JpgDecHal::~JpgDecHal
12-27 19:51:45.639: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x18d8178
12-27 19:51:45.642: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x1947378
12-27 19:51:45.836: D/OpenGLRenderer(10777): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

this starts when I press the back

```
12-27 19:51:48.650: I/not null recipientlist(10777): show
12-27 19:51:48.650: I/in getconversation for complete mesages(10777): show
12-27 19:51:49.103: D/dalvikvm(10777): GC_EXPLICIT freed 587K, 14% free 10675K/12359K, paused 2ms+5ms
12-27 19:51:49.644: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x18d8178
12-27 19:51:49.647: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE  cookie 0x1947378
12-27 19:51:49.770: D/OpenGLRenderer(10777): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

again when I press back

```
12-27 19:51:51.606: I/not null recipientlist(10777): show
12-27 19:51:51.607: I/in getconversation for complete mesages(10777): show
12-27 19:51:52.383: D/dalvikvm(10777): GC_EXPLICIT freed 615K, 13% free 10781K/12359K, paused 1ms+6ms
12-27 19:51:52.511: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x18d8178
12-27 19:51:52.513: D/IPCThreadState(10777): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x1947378
12-27 19:51:52.631: D/OpenGLRenderer(10777): Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-27 19:51:56.522: D/OpenGLRenderer(10777): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

It depends on the size of this `recipientlist` which I am taking from the previous activity via intent.If its size is 1,back works fine,if size is 2,back needs two consective press to get back to the previous activity as log has been shown for the case of size=3.
and getconversation is the method that is called when I check in my onResume() that list is not null

Comment: have you overriden onBackPressed()? if so update your code

Comment: Can you post your log from starting this `Activity` and then pressing back button?

Comment: No, I didnot override the buttons...

Comment: @aneelasafdar : you means onResume of Current Activity in user pressed back button or onResume of previous  Activity?

Comment: of current activity...it would not be any problem if the previous activity's onResume() would get called..

Comment: @aneelasafdar : can you plz share some relevant code from Activity

Comment: I just figure out it was the problem lies in the previous activity and the problem was that I was trying to `startActivity(myntent)` in a loop :P So problem wa just to exclude the line from the loop and everything worked as expected :)